# Is this correct: Inflection points of Euler number graph in Island-Mainland transition correspond to spanning cluster site percolation threshold?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, percolation

I'm writing with respect to this paper: [Khatun, Dutta, and Tarafdar - "Islands in Sea" and "Lakes in Mainland" phases and related transitions simulated on a square lattice](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjb/e2017-80365-3)

Here's a link to the [PDF version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1onBqzq50ApMzyvgMYekvjXdUXRbuhoZN/view).

$\chi(p)$ has been defined as $N_B(p)-N_W(p)$ where $N_B(p)$ and $N_W(p)$ are the number of black clusters and white clusters respectively at a probability $p$. [$p$ is the probability of a square being black]

[image]

Now, in this image (from the cited paper), we can see the graphical plots of $\chi$ vs. $p$ graphs for different system sizes. As the system size increases there are two inflection points (say at $P_{L1}$ and $P_{L2}$) which become more and more prominent. One of my lab-mates plotted the graphs for $L=500$ and $L=1000$ and reported that those two inflections points were slowly tending towards $P_1=1-0.59$ and $P_2=0.59$.

So, basically their claim was that:

$$\lim_{L\to\infty} P_{L1} = P_1 = 0.41$$

$$\lim_{L\to\infty} P_{L2} = P_2 = 0.59$$

Surprisingly, $0.59$ is the exact site percolation threshold for square lattice (with $z=4,\bar{z}=4$), as stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_threshold).

I've been thinking about this for quite some time, but I have no idea as to why the inflection point as $L\to\infty$ would converge to $0.59$ (i.e. spanning cluster site percolation threshold). Their claim might also be wrong, since they had just done the plotting for just upto $L=1000$. I would be glad if someone can prove that the claim is "wrong" (or even "right").

Also, is there any mathematically "exact" way to predict the values of $p$'s, at which the two inflections respectively occur?